# Auto refreshing a jsp page not working

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have jsp page which loads data from `ArrayList` passed by the corresponding servlet. i have `response.setIntheader("Refresh",60)` which is suppose to refresh my jsp page after every `60 seconds`. but this does not happen. it shows a blank page with servlet url in the browser.

Comment: try `response.addHeader("Refresh","60");` or if you want to do it using Javascript ten you can use jQuery functions also.

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you wait for 60 seconds?
2. Maybe getting overwritten after your call .. "If the header had already been set, the new value overwrites the previous one. "
3. Maybe you are setting the header too late, after the response has been committed in which case you should be encountering IllegalStateException.

Comment: yes i waited for 60 sec i was getting illegalStateException previously....but then i added return statement after rd.forward method.....so now i don't see any illegalStateException in my eclipse console.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh your jsp completely, you may try this in your jsp itself:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60"/><!-- content is in seconds -->
```